# Could you help me identifying this font?

Tags: font-identification

This is unfortunately all I have:

[image: Small]

[image: Big]

I tried finding it with Identifont and WhatTheFont, but I had no success. The closest typeface I could find is [Trelic](http://www.whatfontis.com/Tralic.font?text=uvicryba@), but the `y` does not match.

Comment: Where did you come across the font, if I may ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest I've found is Khmer MN, although there is a slightly sharper vertex in the u and y and a different @ symbol

[image: KhmerMn]